# Best practice for via stitching of multiple GND planes with analog and digital on different PCB sides

Tags: ground-plane, mixed-signal, stitching

I'm quite well aware of standard practices of grounding in mixed signal application. I bascially always use just one large common ground and use wise component placement to keep current transients away from the sensitive analog regions.

But now I have an application, where analog and digital regions are on the opposite layers, completely overlapping due to tiny PCB size. I use a 4 Layer PCB and have routing almost exclusively on the outer layers, leaving the two inner layers for ground.
At the moment I have the two ground layers connected only at the place where voltage supply and SPI interface go from top to bottom, no additional stitching of the ground layers in other regions. I think that makes sense, as there are no other places where signals penetrate through the stack, but I'm not completely sure it's the best solution.

**Q:** Should I add additional GND stitching distributed over the PCB, connecting analog and digital ground planes? Does it have any advantages or disadvantages? Or does it likely not make any difference at all?

I would like to have an answer that preferably is as general/universal as possible, but this is my specific use case:
I have a DAQ system with quite sensitive inputs in the upper µV range and high-ish input impedance (~50 kOhm ... 1 MOhm). The digital part is running only with a few mA and a few tens of MHz. An LDO on the bottom layer is filtering noise from the supply.

The image is not to scale, both analog and digital parts stretch over most of the PCB. I just separated them a bit in this graphic for clarity. The large In+ and In- blocks is the analog input circuitry.
[image]

Comment: What else about the DAQ? -- is it a S-D converter or sampling/SAR/etc.? Will it actually pick up digital noise, or reject it? How much opportunity is there to filter such noise (at the ADC input, or digitally afterwards)?  "Upper µV" (100s, 300s?) implies a low risk, I would say, but still deserving of consideration. What about testing, do you have any opportunity to put together a test build of the DAQ system separately, and subject it to interference, especially ground injection on key components?

Comment: If you think the answer could vary between different ADC topologies, I would prefer an answer explaining these different behaviours, but I would assume that this is a more general problem, independent of the ADC. I assume whether or not stitching the two layers all over the board is more a question of noise coupling. The ADC in this question could in theorie stand for every "kind-of-sensitive" analog circuit. Also the input voltage range should not really matter. If different ground-stitching topologies are preferable for 50µV vs 500µV I would kindly ask you to eleborate on this as well.

Comment: Sounds like you really don't need two GND layers, particularly if you're going to go to the trouble to stitch the two GND layers together.  One would suffice

Comment: That might be the case, yes. But double layer definitely wouldn't cut it, so I have the two middle layers no matter what. And since I'm quite eager to avoid any noticable noise from the DC/DC or any digital stuff, I'm trying to figure out what the best way might be. Maybe it does not matter at all. Since there seems to be no clear answer here I figure thats likely the case. But I thought there might be some deeper inside into grounding and shielding strategies that I missed so far and that is applicable in this scenario ;)

Comment: Maybe use one of the inner layers (2 or 3) for additional routing, and just keep a single GND plane?  That may eliminate the need to pass signals from layer 1 to 4, & vice versa.

Comment: The only signals passing through the board are the ones connecting the analog and the digital domain: SPI and Vcc. Otherwise the two domains are pretty self contained.

Answer (score 0):

Stitching will make a difference in two ways:

1. planar mode resonances between the ground planes. Obviously you can have them only where a quarter \$\lambda\$ fits between the edges approximately (a bit lower actually because of the via inductances) With stitching you push this region to much higher frequencies.
2. Transfer impedance for the signals going from the top side to the bottom side. That can be the SPI signals but also the current fluctuations in the supplies. You always lower the transfer impedance by stitching, a lot of stitches around the transitions would already do most of that job. The importance is that lower transfer impedance will induce less potential difference between the ground planes, so it will reduce emission, even in the frequency region below the planar mode resonances.

So in general (a bit of) stitching will still help, but only if you are expecting the kind of problems mentioned above.

Two differences: